# Why am I getting an error while running ant sonar command in cmd?

Tags: xml, ant, sonarqube

I am trying to basically build my ant project and check the results in sonarqube .When I am trying to run the ant sonar command at my root directory , this error is thrown .
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried removing the extra space between property tags in my *build.xml* file. Working fine. Didn't know a single space can be a huge problem .